# driver.terminateApp giving error is still running after 500ms timeout on Android real device

Tags: appium

Getting error when we use driver.terminateApp(PackageName)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'com.apkpure.aegon' is still running after 500ms timeout

Can you let me know How to reslove it @Ron Werner

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'com.apkpure.aegon' is still running after 500ms timeout